Finding Highest element in an Array [C programming]
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ele;
    printf("Enter the required number of elements:");
    scanf("%d", &ele);
    int arr[ele];
    for (int i = 0; i < ele; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter value for the array:\n");
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    // printing the array
    int len;
    int larger;
    len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (int z = 0; z < len; z++)
    {
        printf("Array elements is %d\t", arr[z]);
    }
    // finding the largest element in the array
    for (int y = 0; y < len; y++)
    {
        larger = arr[y];
        if (larger > 0)
        {
            if (arr[y] > larger)
            {
                larger = y;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (arr[y] < larger)
            {
                larger = y;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The largerst element in the array is:%d", arr[larger]);
}

I'm creating this C programme to find the highest element in the array , whether it be -ve or +ve.
I'm getting correct answer for positive elements but not for negative ones.
For e.g we know that -10 is greater than -40 , but my program shows -40 as the larger element.

Your "finding the largest element" loop will always set largest to the value of the last element of the array, which is not useful.  As a result the arr[y] < larger tests will always be false.

OT: why for (int z;... and for (int y;... ? Just use for (int i;... everywhere.

Unrelated: you don't need to compute the number of elements in the array (the sizeof/sizeof thing); you already have that in ele.

Normally, you start with first element being largest and then compare elements 1..n-1. This avoids any issues with comparing first element

Keep only the index of largest element, no need from variable for value. And don't forget to initialize it (e.g. to first element).

@Anonymous Do you want to find the element with the largest arithmetic value or the largest absolute value?

The loop to find the largest element is incorrect:
    // finding the largest element in the array
    for (int y = 0; y < len; y++)
    {
        larger = arr[y];  // why set larger here?
                          // also larger should be an index, not a value
        if (larger > 0)
        {
            if (arr[y] > larger)  // always false: arr[y] == larger
            {
                larger = y;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (arr[y] < larger)  // always false: arr[y] == larger
            {
                larger = y;
            }
        }
    }

Hence larger is always the last value in the array, so the next statement will have undefined behavior if this value is not positive and less than ele.
It is unclear whether you want to find the element with the larger value, as you mention -10 is larger than -40 or if you want to find the element with the largest absolute value.
For the first case, the comparison suffices, no special case is needed for negative values. The loop can be simplified to:
    // finding the largest element in the array
    int larger = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < len; y++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[larger]) {
            larger = i;
        }
    }

Here is a modified version of the program:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int len;
    printf("Enter the required number of elements: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &len) != 1)
        return 1;
    if (len < 0 || len > 1024) {
        printf("invalid length: %d\n", len);
        return 1;
    }
    int arr[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("Enter value for the array:\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    // printing the array
    printf("Array elements:");
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    // finding the largest element in the array
    int largest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < len; y++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[largest]) {
            largest = i;
        }
    }
    printf("The largest element in the array is: %d at index %d\n",
           arr[largest], largest);
    return 0;
}

For the largest absolute value, you can use the abs() function defined in <stdlib.h>.
#include <stdlib.h>

...

    // finding the element with the largest absolute value
    int largest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < len; y++) {
        if (abs(arr[i]) > abs(arr[largest])) {
            largest = i;
        }
    }

Note however that the abs() function has undefined behavior for INT_MIN because the most negative int value has a larger absolute value than INT_MAX on systems that represent signed integers using two's complement, which is mandated by the C2x revision of the C Standard.
To avoid this pitfall, one can simply add a test for this special case:
#include <limits.h>

...

    // finding the element with the largest absolute value
    int largest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; y++) {
        if (arr[i] == INT_MIN) {
            largest = i;
            break;
        }
        if (abs(arr[i]) > abs(arr[largest])) {
            largest = i;
        }
    }

If you are not allowed to use library functions, you can write your own to determine the negative absolute value, which is defined for all int values:'
int neg_abs(int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return n;
    else
        return -n;
}

and use this function in the simple loop:
    // finding the element with the largest absolute value
    int largest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < len; y++) {
        if (neg_abs(arr[i]) < neg_abs(arr[largest])) {
            largest = i;
        }
    }


@Anonymous: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.
